# How to print in a row not perpendicularly

Tags: java

I have to print trees horizontally, but it prints perpendicularly:

```
public void start(){
printTrees(3,4);
}

private void printTrees(int hight, int amount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    tree();
}
 private void tree() {
    String a =  "    *";
    String b ="  *****";
    String c =" *******";
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Now it prints like this:

```
   *
 *****
*******
   *
 *****
*******
   *
 *****
*******
   *
 *****
*******
```

The trees look good but I want them to be in a row like this:

```
   *         *          *         *
 *****     *****      *****     *****
*******   *******    *******   *******
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part is to understand that, for each line, you will need to print all asterixes (and spaces) of that level.

You can do the following:

```
private static String printTrees(int level, int treesCount) {
    int marginBetweenTrees = 3;

    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < treesCount; i++) { // top of the tress (first line)
        addTreeLine(0, level, strBuilder);
        IntStream.range(0, marginBetweenTrees).forEach(value -> strBuilder.append(' '));
    }
    strBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator());

    for (int i = 1, sideAstrixCount = 2; i < level; i++, sideAstrixCount++) { // rest of the trees (other lines)
        int sideSpaces = (level - 1 - i);

        for (int j = 0; j < treesCount; j++) {
            addTreeLine(sideAstrixCount, sideSpaces, strBuilder);
            IntStream.range(0, marginBetweenTrees).forEach(value -> strBuilder.append(' '));
        }

        strBuilder.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    return strBuilder.toString();
}

private static void addTreeLine(int sideAstrixCount, int sideSpaces, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
    IntStream.range(0,sideSpaces).forEach(value -> stringBuilder.append(' '));
    IntStream.range(0, sideAstrixCount).forEach(value -> stringBuilder.append('*'));
    stringBuilder.append('*');
    IntStream.range(0, sideAstrixCount).forEach(value -> stringBuilder.append('*'));
    IntStream.range(0,sideSpaces).forEach(value -> stringBuilder.append(' '));
}
```

`printTrees(3,4)` output:

```
   *         *         *         *      
 *****     *****     *****     *****    
*******   *******   *******   *******
```

`printTrees(6,3)` output:

```
      *               *               *         
    *****           *****           *****       
   *******         *******         *******      
  *********       *********       *********     
 ***********     ***********     ***********    
*************   *************   *************
```

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite this method to return String. It only returns first and last line. Middle lines are missing. How it should be changed?  I've been fighting with this for 3 days now ;D

Comment: @Mannual I don't understand. My solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: It works great! But now i need this method to return this trees in one  String instead of printing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
public static void start(){
        printTrees(3,4);
    }

    private static void printTrees(int hight, int amount) {

        String a="   *   ";
        String b =" ***** ";
        String c ="*******";


        String[] tab={a,b,c};
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            //tree();
            for (int j=0;j<3 ;j++ ) {
            

                System.out.print(tab[i]+"  ");
           
            }
            System.out.println();  
        }
    }
```